# Android template error Transformation.map

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tabbed, tabbed-view

I've tryied to use a template (tabbed view activity) in a new project (java).. but it won't run (no code modifications). Version 2.1.2 on Win 11
error given:

> C:\Progetti\Android\Test\app\src\main\java\it\gattoneroph\test\ui\main\PageViewModel.java:12: error: method map in class Transformations cannot be applied to given types;
> private LiveData mText = Transformations.map(mIndex, new Function<Integer, String>() {
> ^
> required: LiveData,Function1<X,Y>
> found: MutableLiveData,<anonymous Function<Integer,String>>
> reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) X,Y
> (argument mismatch; <anonymous Function<Integer,String>> cannot be converted to Function1<X,Y>)
> where X,Y are type-variables:
> X extends Object declared in method <X,Y>map(LiveData,Function1<X,Y>)
> Y extends Object declared in method <X,Y>map(LiveData,Function1<X,Y>)

class

```
public class PageViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<Integer> mIndex = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private LiveData<String> mText = Transformations.map(mIndex, new Function<Integer, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(Integer input) {
            return "Hello world from section: " + input;
        }
    });

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        mIndex.setValue(index);
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

why? I've no idea why this template seems to be broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [this known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/273613690#comment2), the template is generating the code expected by earlier versions of the Lifecycle library. However, that code changed in [Lifecycle 2.6.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.6.0).

As your error message says, replace `new Function` with `new Function1`, which is the expected class when using Lifecycle 2.6.0 or higher.

Comment: thank you (I'm only a beginner so .. i get stucked by simple problems)

Answer (score 2):

1- Replace **Function** to **Function1** like following

```
new Function<Integer, String>(){}
```

to

```
new Function1<Integer, String>()
```

2- implement the required method

```
@Override
        public String invoke(Integer input) {
            return "Hello world from section: " + input;
        }
```

thanks it is working with me :)

Answer (score 1):

I converted or replace the

`Transformations.map(mIndex, new Function<Integer, String>() {`

to lambda.

Since changing it to new Function1 doesn't work for me.

Comment: Worked for me thanks.